# Linux command line: split a string

Tags: string, bash, split

I have long file with the following list:

```
/drivers/isdn/hardware/eicon/message.c//add_b1()
/drivers/media/video/saa7134/saa7134-dvb.c//dvb_init()
/sound/pci/ac97/ac97_codec.c//snd_ac97_mixer_build()
/drivers/s390/char/tape_34xx.c//tape_34xx_unit_check()
(PROBLEM)/drivers/video/sis/init301.c//SiS_GetCRT2Data301()
/drivers/scsi/sg.c//sg_ioctl()
/fs/ntfs/file.c//ntfs_prepare_pages_for_non_resident_write()
/drivers/net/tg3.c//tg3_reset_hw()
/arch/cris/arch-v32/drivers/cryptocop.c//cryptocop_setup_dma_list()
/drivers/media/video/pvrusb2/pvrusb2-v4l2.c//pvr2_v4l2_do_ioctl()
/drivers/video/aty/atyfb_base.c//aty_init()
/block/compat_ioctl.c//compat_blkdev_driver_ioctl()
....
```

It contains all the functions in the kernel code. The notation is `file//function`.

I want to copy some 100 files from the kernel directory to another directory, so I want to strip every line from the function name, leaving just the filename.

It's super-easy in python, any idea how to write a 1-liner in the bash prompt that does the trick?

Thanks,

Udi

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
cat "func_list" | sed "s#//.*##" > "file_list"
```

Didn't run it :)

Comment: BTW +1 for the courage of publishing it without testing it!

Comment: @Dennis Yeah, I know. I always forget backup syntax and I'm usually trying to give non destructive commands, especially if I don't run them beforehand :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use pure Bash:

```
while read -r line; do echo "${line%//*}"; done < funclist.txt
```

**Edit:**

The syntax of the `echo` command is doing the same thing as the `sed` command in Eugene's answer: deleting the "//" and everything that comes after.

Broken down:

> "echo ${line}" is the same as "echo $line"
>   the "%" deletes the pattern that follows it if it matches the trailing portion of the parameter
>   "%" makes the shortest possible match, "%%" makes the longest possible
>   "//*" is the pattern to match, "`*`" is similar to `sed`'s ".`*`"

See the Parameter Expansion section of the Bash `man` page for more information, including:

- using `${parameter#word}` for matching the beginning of a parameter
- `${parameter/pattern/string}` to do `sed`-style replacements
- `${parameter:offset:length}` to retrieve substrings
- etc.

Comment: Can you please explain the syntax within rhe "echo", for future generations reading your answer?

Answer (score 4):

here's a one liner in (g)awk

```
awk -F"//" '{print $1}' file
```

Comment: What's the major difference between awk and sed?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one using cut and rev

```
cat file | rev | cut -d'/' -f2-| rev
```